# Set parameter inside SQL server execute command

Tags: sql, if-statement, dynamic, parameters, execute

I want to assign the value to a parameter PRGMREFID inside the if-else condition using the execute commands. Each time I try to do that, it shows NULL value assigned to PRGMREFID parameter, and if I place its declare command inside SEt @C, I do not find the parameter PRGMREFID outside of if-else. How to do that pls help.

Below is the patch.

```
DECLARE @C VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @PRGMREFID VARCHAR(10)

IF 1=1
SET @C = 'set '+ (@PRGMREFID) +' = ''X''  '
else
set @c = ''

EXECUTE(@C)
select @PRGMREFID
```

Answer (score 0):

To do what you are trying to do you need to use `sp_executesql` and define the parameter as an `output parameter` in order to have the value returned to your session's local variable:

```
DECLARE @C NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @PRGMREFID VARCHAR(10)

if 1=1
  set @C = 'set @PRGMREFID = ''X'' '
else
  set @C = ''

exec sp_executesql @C, N'@PRGMREFID VARCHAR(10) output', @PRGMREFID output

select @PRGMREFID
```